# Проверка ID пользователя через БД. SQLite, vk_api

Tags: python, sqlite, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть база данных, в ней таблица с 4 значениям, при проверке пользователя мне нужно всего лишь одно значение это `uid`. Работаю одновременно с vk_api, суть заключается в том, что при запросе команды, код проверяет, нахожусь ли я в БД или нет:

```
if request == '/+бд': # Загрузка пользователей беседы в БД.

            import sqlite3

            Connect = sqlite3.connect('CaptureBotDB.db')
            Cursor = Connect.cursor()
            cid = event.chat_id

            sql = """SELECT uid FROM AdminsInChat WHERE cid = ?;"""
            Connect.execute(sql, (str(cid)))

            checkAdmin = Cursor.fetchall()

            if user_id in checkAdmin:
                loadDB() # Функция.
            else:
                write_msg(vk, chat_id, error02)
```

Команда работает, код пишет мне ошибку, если я не в БД, но есть проблема. Когда я себя туда добавил, код, всё равно пишет тоже самое.

Что не так? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `Connect.execute(sql, (str(cid),))`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, Это ничего на даёт, всё, тоже самое.

Comment: `>код пишет мне ошибку`. Текст ошибки всегда надо приводить. Не всегда ошибки программиста так очевидны.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, в консоли ни каких ошибок нету.

Comment: Вы проверяли, что у Вас в `checkAdmin` после получения результатов запроса?

Comment: Вы уверены, что при добавлении Вы не допустили ту же ошибку? Приведите в тексте вопроса код, который добавляет в базу.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, базу он почему-то не видит. Через `print` вывел - пусто. На счёт добавление в БД, это всё работает, за это не стоит беспокоиться.

Comment: Есть онлайн просмоторщики sqlite баз данных, воспользуйтесь ими, посмотрите что там вообще есть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97214/discussion-between-hoojpop-and--).

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97214/discussion-between-hoojpop-and--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Connect.execute(sql, (str(cid)))` - запросы к БД делаются через объект курсора, а не через объект соединения
2. Функция [`execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) в качестве второго аргумента принимает **итерируемый** объект параметров (список, кортеж, генератор, строку и т.д.). Вы же передаёте туда строку, что воспринимается, как итерируемый объект *символов*, т.е. в запрос `SELECT uid FROM AdminsInChat WHERE cid = ?;`
   вместо знаков `?` "пытается" подставиться каждый символ строки. И если бы у Вас в `cid` содержалось число, содержащее более одной цифры, то у Вас бы сработало исключение. Например, для `cid = 23` Вы бы получили исключение: `sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.` Поэтому Вам надо передавать итерируемый объект, содержащий строку. Например, список: `Cursor.execute(sql, [str(cid)])`.
3. Как выяснилось из [чата](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97214/), колонка `cid` в Вашей БД имеет тип INTEGER, Вы же туда пытаетесь передать строку. Я не знаю, как ведёт себя sqlite, если ему в запросе вместо числа скормить строку, но лучше всё же перестраховаться и передавать именно число. Т.к. я не знаю наверняка, какой тип имеет переменная `cid` в Вашем коде, то с использованием явного приведения это будет выглядеть так: `Cursor.execute(sql, [int(cid)])`.
4. `checkAdmins` у Вас после этого является **списком**, содержащим **кортежи**, которые представляют собой строки из таблицы. И Вам необходимо проверить, есть ли Ваш `user_id` среди этих строк. Условие будет таким: `if user_id in (row[0] for row in checkAdmins):`.