# Как вывести все значение в переменной из БД. SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, vkontakte-api

есть код на вывод переменной из БД форматом `integer`. Одновременно работаю с vk_api.

Вот код:

```
def ShowUsers():

       import sqlite3

       Connect = sqlite3connect('.db')
       Cursor = Connect.cursor()

       SQL = """SELECT user_id FROM ListMembers WHERE chat_id = ? AND push = 1;"""
       # user_id - ID пользователя.
       # chat_id - ID чата.
       # push - Значение с помощью которого человеку приходит уведомление. Если push = 0, то уведомление не придёт.
       Connect.execute(SQL, (str(event.chat_id)))

       for user in Cursor.fetchall():

             msg = f"@id{user}({first_name})" + '\n' # При выводе в ВК, получится вот так: Вася - @id0(Вася)." 

        vk.messages.send(chat_id = chat_id, message = msg, random_id = 0)
```

БД:

```
first_name    user_id   chat_id   push
Вася              1        1       1             
Максим            2        1       1             
Лера              3        1       1
```

Есть проблема, выводит только имя Вася. Пробовал `"""SELECT user_id IN() ... """` - не работает.

Что не так, подскажите.

Comment: Опять Вы запросы делаете через объект соединения, а не через курсор.

Comment: `f"@id{user}({first_name})"` - где у Вас переменная `first_name`?

Comment: У Вас все те же ошибки из [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011582/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-id-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%91%d0%94-sqlite-vk-api), в котором я Вам помогал.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, На счёт `first_name`, я забыл его дописать в вопрос, пишу с телефона, неудобно. На счет курсора, да забыл. Простите.